# Is "subordinated" a good translation of the Italian legal term "subordinato"?

Tags: british-english, translation, legalese

I've found this translation http://www.wordreference.com/iten/subordinato but I am not sure if English legals use subordinate to define a party that is subordinated to another.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: An approximation of "subordinato" can be "working for someone that employs you".

Comment: It's a perfectly common usage in English too - but we just call such a person a "subordinate" (not *subordinated*).

Comment: ...most of these thousands of instances of ["behaviour towards subordinates"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22behaviour+towards+subordinates%22&oq=%22behaviour+towards+subordinates%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.18864650&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will be for this exact context, which I'm voting to close as General Reference.

Comment: I am drafting an agreement where I am say something like "Section x - Exclusion of partnership relationship and employment of party x" OR "Section x - Exclusion of partnership relationship and subordinate relationship"

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, so I wouldn't want to advise on phrasing of a (legal?) agreement. But if you simply look at a few examples in that link I'd have thought it will tell you as much as any answer here, since *"behaviour towards subordinates"* is often an area that concerns the law. Sexual language/activity involving a subordinate is often discouraged, and may be illegal, for example.

Answer (score 1):

English "subordinate" implies a hierarchy, but not necessarily an employment relationship. For example, the subordinates of a military officer are those of lower rank whom he commands. The word need not refer to a hierarchy of persons at all: it is also used to describe nesting in an outline of an argument or essay. From your comment, I guess a reference to an employer/employee relationship is more precise.

Answer (score 1):

The legal term *subordinated* may have a narrow technical definition, which can't be guessed without some context.

For example, *subordinated debt* will have a specific definition not closely related to normal English use of the word *subordinate*.

---

In normal English, the final definition

- *militare (inferiore di grado)* military :

  - subordinate *n*

is the primary use, and the penultimate definition

- *(sottoposto)* :

  - subordinate, direct report *n*
  - aide, associate *n*
  - *pejorative* stooge, underling  *n*

would be a less-common but still understandable use.

The other definitions (conditional, dependent or non-autonomous) would be more likely in specific, narrow or technical sense.